# How to Fix 'colnames" error in a simulation in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, montecarlo

Using a simulation in R, I am trying to test consistency of selection criterion, but I keep getting the following error :

> "Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = make.names(np)) :    attempt
> to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions"

How do I fix this error ?

```
set.seed(1)
X <- rnorm(100)
noise <- rnorm(100)

Y <- 3 + 1*X + 4*X + 6*X + noise

require(leaps)
df <- data.frame(Y, X)
fit <- regsubsets(Y~X, data = df, nvmax = 10)

fit_summary <- summary(fit)

require(tidyverse);require(ggplot2);require(ggthemes);

data_frame(Cp = fit_summary$cp,
           BIC = fit_summary$bic,
           AdjR2 = fit_summary$adjr2) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    gather(value_type, value, -id) %>%
    ggplot(aes(id, value, col = value_type)) +
    geom_line() + geom_point() + ylab('') + xlab('Number of Variables Used') +
    facet_wrap(~ value_type, scales = 'free') +
    theme_tufte() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a design matrix with only one column, selection doesn't really make sense in that case, does it? If you add another column, the code starts working.

```
set.seed(1)
X <- rnorm(100)
X2 <- rnorm(100)
noise <- rnorm(100)
Y <- 3 + 1*X + 4*X2 + noise

df <- data.frame(Y, X, X2)
fit <- leaps::regsubsets(Y~., data = df, nvmax = 10)
```